# Fetch Country/City wise data from MySql table using Latitude and Longitude colomns

Tags: mysql, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Here is my sample table

```
table name: activitylog

id |    activity  |  lat        |   long
---+--------------+-------------+-------------
 1 |  activity1   | 11.2742848  |  75.8013801
 2 |  activity2   | 11.2742848  |  75.8013801
 3 |  activity3   | 11.2742848  |  75.8013801
 4 |  activity4   | 11.2742848  |  75.8013801
```

I have to select entries which belong to specific countries/cities from above. There is no separate column for country or city. I am bothered about  google's **Geolocation API**. But for a long table, checking each entry whether belong it my area is very slow process

Do I need store all the Lat and Long details in another table? which is best practice?

**Edit:** In my case, storing city or country info above table is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to do that...

There is a free Google Geocoding API provides this service via a HTTP REST API. Note, the API is usage and rate limited, but you can pay for unlimited access.

Try this link to see an example of the output (this is in json, output is also available in XML)

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=11.2742848,75.8013801&sensor=true

OR

There is a web service that returns a country code and takes as parameters the lat and long.

Here is an example: http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=49.03&lng=10.2&username=demo

I also found a little description:

> The iso country code of any given point.
>
> - Webservice Type: REST
> - Url: ws.geonames.org/countryCode?
> - Parameters: lat, lng, type, lang,
>   radius (buffer in km for closest country in coastal areas)
> - Result:
>   returns the iso country code for the given latitude/longitude
>
> With the
> parameter type=xml this service returns an xml document with iso
> country code and country name. The optional parameter lang can be used
> to specify the language the country name should be in. JSON output is
> produced with type=JSON

Please note that you should create a user account at http://www.geonames.org/login in order to use the service.

Comment: How can I apply this API for long table? I think its take long time if I use this API for each entry. I want select only entry belong specific City or Country.

Comment: why not store this info also in table...when you are storing activity log in table. In this way you can directly fetch data. Although there are free DB availbale containing lat,long with city mapping..but i don't recommend using that

Comment: In my case altering table is not not possible. So that i am looking another way.